# What are the alternatives to paypal for non-supported countries?

Tags: web-services, paypal, payment, currency

Not sure whether to ask this question here but here is the question.

What are the alternatives to paypal for countries whom paypal does not support?

For example, I am from Pakistan and i am looking for easy way like paypal to transfer and receive amounts from the services buyers whom i render my freelance service.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like [**Google Checkout**](http://checkout.google.com/). They support a much larger range of countries than Paypal does (yes, Pakistan is one of them), and the rates are comparable.

Answer (score 4):

PayPal is not a safe solution to receive money even in countries where it is accepted. Account of sellers gets frozen without explanation.

If you're a company, you could try to register with some credit card processing company so that you can accept credit cards.

Or just open a bank account and let people send you money via SWIFT.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a payment card processer like [CyberSource](http://www.cybersource.com/products_and_services/global_payment_services/credit_card_processing/), though this might be overkill (fees, cost of implementation) for your scenario.